# R/Shiny: Plotly reactive height discarded after window resize

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

After upgrade from Plotly 4.5.6 to Plotly 4.6.0 (or higher), the plot height is incorrectly calculated when set reactively in `plot_ly`. This happens upon window resizing or tabsetPanel selection.

**Prerequisites**

- Plotly height is chosen via `plot_ly(..., height=<some dependency>)`
- `<some dependency>` is a reactive Value (`input$height` in the example below)

**Problem**

- after resizing window, the height is set to the first value of the selectInput

**Example**

- When chosen "800" in the selectInput, the plot is correctly drawn with a height of 800px:

[image: ex1]

- After a resize of the window, the height is changed to the first value of the `selectInput` (100px), even though this value did not change at all:

[image: ex2]

The same problem happens if there is a `tabsetPanel` in the page (e.g. below the plot). The plot height is changed when a different tab is clicked.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)


ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(
       selectInput("height", "Choose desired height", choices=c(100,800)), 
       plotlyOutput("plot")))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output, session){
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(mtcars, x=~gear, y=~cyl, height = input$height)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**What I tried so far**

1. Putting the `height` argument in `renderPlotly` works initially, but since the Plotly itself does never change its height, the plot itself stays at 800px the whole time (just the container height is changed):

ui:  `uiOutput("plot")`

server:

```
output$plot <- renderUI({ plotlyOutput("plotly", height=input$height) })  
output$plotly <- renderPlotly({ plot_ly(mtcars, x=~gear, y=~cyl)})
```

2. When I additionally make `output$plotly` dependent on `input$height`, the Plots "jumps" immediately after selecting any other height:

`output$plotly <- renderPlotly({ plot_ly(mtcars, x=~gear, y=~cyl,  height=input$height) })`

Note that all of this also happens if there is a simple `tabsetPanel` below the plot and another tab is chosen there.

Comment: Have you tried using the height argument in `renderPlotly` rather than `plot_ly`?

Comment: doesn't work. Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed finally, see [this bug on github:](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1068). In plotly package **version 4.8.0** this behaviour is corrected.

Note that you need to add the height of 100% to plotlyOutput, i.e. `plotlyOutput("plot", height = '100%')` for a complete solution (this sets the invisible container space appropriately).